# Error reported when doing Boston house price predict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

(Sorry, I am not a native-English speaker)
I am trying to make a Boston house price prediction. And the following is the Error report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2022.2\scratches\scratch_33.py", line 19, in <module>
    features = boston.data
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5902, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'. Did you mean: '_data'?
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
If you can give a hand. thanks a lot.
PS: It seems that load_boston is banned now. So I use the dataset in local.

The more code are as the followings:

```py
class Boston(QWidget):
        
            # 交互
            chooseBtn = QPushButton("预测房价", self)
            chooseBtn.setFixedSize(200, 50)
            chooseBtn.move(600, 500)
            chooseBtn.clicked.connect(self.show_result)

            self.showEdit = QTextEdit(self)
            self.showEdit.setFixedSize(350, 360)
            self.showEdit.move(520, 110)

            self.city_data = self.load_data()  # 载入波士顿房价数据
            self.split_data(self.city_data())

        def load_data(self):
                boston = df
                return boston

        def explore_city_data(self, city_data):
                SalePrice = city_data.target  #预测目标
                housing_features = city_data._data
                num_houses = np.shape(city_data._data)
                num_features = np.shape(city_data._data)
                min_price = np.min(city_data.target)
                max_price = np.max(city_data.target)
                mean_price = np.mean(city_data.target)
                median_price = np.median(city_data.target)
                stand_dev = np.std(city_data.target)

                baseInfo = str("=====================================" +
                               "\n\nBoston房价数据集中共有" + str(num_houses) + "组数据。\n\n" +
                               "\n房价最高为" + str(max_price) + "\n房价最低为" + str(min_price) +
                               "\n房价中值为" + str(median_price) + "\n房价均值为" + str(mean_price) +
                               "\n房价标准差为" + str(stand_dev))
                self.showEdit.append(baseInfo)

        def split_data(self, city_data):  #分割数据
                X, y = city_data.data, city_data.target
                self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.30,random_state=42)

        def performance_metric(self, label, prediction):
                mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(label, prediction)
                return mse

        def learning_curve(self, depth, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
                sizes = np.round(np.linspace(1, len(X_train), 50))
                train_err = np.zeros(len(sizes))
                test_err = np.zeros(len(sizes))

                for i, s in enumerate(sizes):
                    s = int(s)
                    regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=depth)
                    regressor.fit(X_train[:s], y_train[:s])
                    train_err[i] = self.performance_metric(y_train[:s], regressor.predict(X_train[:s]))
                    test_err[i] = self.performance_metric(y_test, regressor.predict(X_test))

                self.learning_curve_graph(depth, sizes, train_err, test_err)

        def learning_curve_graph(self, depth, sizes, train_err, test_err):
                pl.figure(depth)
                pl.title(str('决策树(深度为' + str(depth) + ')'))
                pl.plot(sizes, test_err, lw=2, label='测试误差')
                pl.plot(sizes, train_err, lw=2, label='训练误差')
                pl.legend()
                pl.xlabel('Training Size')
                pl.ylabel('Error')
                pl.show()

        def model_complexity(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
                max_depth = np.arange(1, 25)
                train_err = np.zeros(len(max_depth))
                test_err = np.zeros(len(max_depth))

                for i, d in enumerate(max_depth):
                    regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=d)
                    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
                    train_err[i] = self.performance_metric(y_train, regressor.predict(X_train))
                    test_err[i] = self.performance_metric(y_test, regressor.predict(X_test))

                self.model_complexity_graph(max_depth, train_err, test_err)

        def model_complexity_graph(self, max_depth, train_err, test_err):
                pl.figure(0)
                pl.title('波士顿房价预测模型——决策树')
                pl.plot(max_depth, test_err, lw=2, label='测试误差')
                pl.plot(max_depth, train_err, lw=2, label='训练误差')
                pl.legend()
                pl.xlabel('Max Depth')
                pl.ylabel('Error')
                pl.show()

        def fit_predict_model(self, city_data):  #预测模型
                X, y = city_data.data, city_data.target
                regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor()
                parameters = {'max_depth': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)}
                scores = make_scorer(metrics.mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False)
                clf = model_selection.GridSearchCV(regressor, parameters, scoring=scores)
                clf.fit(X, y)

                best_clf = clf.best_estimator_
                print(best_clf)

                x = [[float(self.LotArea_Edit.text()), float(self.OverallQual_Edit.text()), float(self.LotFrontage_Edit.text())]]
                y = best_clf.predict(x)

                paramInfo = str('\n\n最佳模型：' + str(clf.best_params_))
                houseInfo = str(
                    '\n\n房屋参数为：\nCRIM   :' + self.CRIM_Edit.text() + "\tZN  :" + self.ZN_Edit.text() + "\n" +
                    "LotArea  :" + self.LotArea_Edit.text() + "\tOverallQual:" + self.OverallQual_Edit.text() + "\n" +
                    "LotFrontage   :" + self.LotFrontage_Edit.text())
                priceInfo = str('\n\n房子的预测价格为：' + str(y[0]) + '\n\n')
                self.showEdit.append(paramInfo)
                self.showEdit.append(houseInfo)
                self.showEdit.append(priceInfo)

        def show_curve(self):
                depth = self.depCombo.currentIndex() + 1
                if depth == 11:
                    max_depths = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
                    for max_depth in max_depths:
                        self.learning_curve(max_depth, self.X_train, self.y_train, self.X_test, self.y_test)
                else:
                    self.learning_curve(depth, self.X_train, self.y_train, self.X_test, self.y_test)

        def show_result(self):
                self.explore_city_data(self.city_data)
                self.model_complexity(self.X_train, self.y_train, self.X_test, self.y_test)
                self.fit_predict_model(self.city_data)
```

Comment: There is a problem with line 19 in scratch_33.py `boston.data` it appears that boston is a dataframe.   There is no attribute 'data' for a dataframe.   Show more of the code and well, see if there is a way to fix this code.

Comment: Did you remember to actually import and load the boston data first? If not, follow the instructions on https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/load-sklearn-boston-housing-data

Comment: The code you posted is not relevant for the current error. Where `features = boston.data` is defined in your code?